# Detecting a second touch while holding a first touch in Cocos2d v3 iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm wanting to be able to detect the following in Cocos2d v3:

A touch is initiated and held, then a second touch occurs somewhere else on the screen. Think of holding with one finger, and tapping with a second.

I've tried to use `- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` but this is only called the first time the second touch occurs, not subsequently.

To be clear, if I hold a touch on the screen and then tap somewhere else, the above method is called. But if I continue holding the first touch and then tap a second time, the above method is not called.

Also, `touchBegan:` is only called when the first touch occurs (i.e. the initial holding touch) and `touchEnded:` is only called when all touches are removed, including the initial holding touch.

**I'd like to know:**

1) How to recognise the above gesture in Cocos2d v3?

2) If 1) isn't possible, would there be a way to do it with my own gesture recogniser, and how would I implement my own gesture recogniser into Cocos2d v3?

Comment: I have implemented a full gesture recognizer in Cocos2d-x (FSM based), but I haven't moved it to CC2D v3 yet.  If you are interested, you can find it at http://nonlinearideas.com/tools-you-build-part-ii-tap-drag-and-pinch/.  Also, you will need to turn on multi-touch by calling something like [__glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES]; when the application is initialized.  **I would post this as the answer, but its not quite what you asked, though I think it will be helpful.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out by default Cocos2d V3 only responds to a single touch by default.

The solution:

```
self.multipleTouchEnabled = TRUE;
```

This means now every new touch will call:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

And every time a finger is lifted from the screen it will call:

```
-(void) touchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Even if there are other touches continuing.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)` then you get each touch count using `pTouches->count();`

Comment: Is this in Cocos2d V3 as well?

Comment: I am not sure it work on v3 but i am using it in cocos2d 2.2. But you can have better idea on touch handling in cocos2d v3 ...just follow this link..                        https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/366/touch-handling-in-cocos2d-30